# Recompose branch to render on top of wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

If i have something like

```
compose(
  withData()
  branch(props => props.isLoading, renderComponent(()=><Spinner />))
)(DataList)
```

what will happen is that the `Spinner` component will replace `DataList` in the DOM while loading.

How can i have the `Spinner` be rendered in addition to `DataList`? Is there some kind of common pattern i can use?

**Live Example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/recompose-branch-forked-zlyuo

Basically what i'd want in this example is to see both 'branched component' and 'wrapped component' at the same time when `showBranched` is `true`

Comment: May you provide a proper [mcve] so we can better understand what you mean?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recompose-branch-forked-zlyuo